# Flutter - spftlite podspec file invalid when performing pod install

Tags: flutter

clueless what to do on this. i Get this specific error

```
    [!] Invalid podspec file at path `(MY DIRECTORY)/progressiverecording/ios/.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios/sqflite.podspec`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did here to fix my problem that eventually fixed my problem was a collection of things.

I got introduced the idea of cleaning/deleting the app's cache file.
then the generic flutter clean; flutter pub get; dart get pub (not 100% if command is correct but this command will install a new cache file) and pod install/update

I used xcode over android studio as it goes more in detail with the problem. Automatically fixed. No way for me to replicate this problem.